# Rails ActiveRecord CounterCache and Callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, counter-cache

Does counter_cache increments and decrements fire active_record callbacks ?

```
User << AR

  has_many :cups

  after_update :do_something

  def do_something
     "Will I be called when number of cups updated ?"
  end

end

Cup << AR

   belongs_to :user, counter_cache: true

end
```

In the above code will the function do_something be called when a new cup is added and it belongs to a user, update will be called on that user to update the cups_count, but from what I have tried it seems like the counter_cache updates don't fire callbacks, may be because they are themselves inside callbacks ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

From the [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/288885f9ebf07a12ce64bc3b4a73e9dbc27eeb40/activerecord/lib/active_record/counter_cache.rb#L84) for counter cache, it seems that ActiveRecord is doing a direct database update, which will skip callbacks.

```
update_all(updates.join(', '), primary_key => id )
```

According to the [documentation for update_all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_all/class), it does skip callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

As @davogones mentions using callbacks is out, but you can still do something similar by overriding the `update_counters` method in your parent object.

In my case I needed to do something if the counter_cache count exceeded a certain value:

```
class Cups < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => true
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :cups

  # This will be called every time there is a counter_cache update, + or - 
  def self.update_counters(id, counters)
    user = User.find(id)
    if user.cups_count + counters['cups_count'] >= some_value
      user.do_something!
    end
    super(id, counters) # continue on with the normal update_counters flow.
  end
end
```

See [update_counters documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/ClassMethods/update_counters) for more info.